# Choosing a Kubernetes flavor for my cluster

Tags: software-development, kubernetes

There are many guides and courses, and most courses will point you to minikube for learning kubernetes. But how do you proceed when you feel like you are ready to take off your learning wheels, and get something into production

- Full blown [Kubernetes installation with separate hardware servers](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/)?
- Kubernetes on vms (like minikube)?
- [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)?
- [k3s](https://k3s.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to go all-in on a Full blown Kubernetes installation and experienced issues regarding installation and configuration. My conclusion is that it depends on your needs (*this is for locally hosted only If you are using a cloud service look at what they recommend*):

### MiniKube

> minikube is local Kubernetes, focusing on making it easy to learn and develop for Kubernetes

[source](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

If you are experimenting and learning, this is probably the quickest way to get started, the stack is locked, and you don't have to learn too much to get started.
This is recommended to get your feet wet and test things you don't know if you will keep.

### [k3s](https://k3s.io/)

This is a breeze to install (there is a self-configuring script you run, as well as easy instructions for adding worker nodes). The stack is *more configurable* than Minikube, and has *less overhead*. If you are working on limited hardware like a Raspberry Pi cluster this is more likely to be your go to. 512mb ram will get you started.
In opposition to Minikube, which has its own set of control tools (e.g. `minikube kubectl ...` you can install the standard kubernetes packages (e.g. on debian based systems:  `sudo apt install kubectl kubeadm`) and use them to administer your cluster (e.g. `kubectl get nodes`)

### Kubernetes (k8s)

This is the solution with the steepest learning curve and the most flexibility. Personally I would say this is for people who love to admin stuff, more suited for environments where there is a team dedicated to the cluster, as opposed to running in the home lab.
Hardware requirements are higher than for k3s.

## Notes to consider:

- If you are using a public cloud provider then I would recommend you use managed offering by them, unless you had a big team that can tackle self managed installations like KOPS it is not recommended to use self managed k8s installations. –
  [Riv P](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/38394/riv-p)

Comment: how does Microk8s compare?